# Javascript page is fully loaded boolean check

Tags: javascript

Short of setting a variable inside of `window.onload`, is there a way to detect if the page has finished loading?

I'm injecting a bit of third party JS in a page that may or may not be fully loaded. I can't modify the page. I can't use JQuery.

I can add a function and poll it repeatedly until it returns true (page fully loaded). Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at jQuery's implementation. Or put your code in the end of DOM tree

Comment: What's the problem with setting a `load` event handler on the `window` object? If you are worried about overriding an existing event handler, use `addEventListener`. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check the [`document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.readyState) property.

From MDN:

> Returns "loading" while the document is loading, "interactive" once it is finished parsing but still loading sub-resources, and **"complete" once it has loaded**.

Answer (score 14):

I would make use of [readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.readyState).

For example first check if the document is loaded, and if not set up a listener:

```
if(document.readyState === 'ready' || document.readyState === 'complete') {
  doSomething();
} else {
  document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
      doSomething();
    }
  }
}
```